# Steps to previewing a fully-functioning Ruby on Rails app in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new at this so apologies for the noobiness of the question.

I've forked & cloned a fully-functioning Ruby on Rails app that I will be editing/playing around with locally. I would like to be able to view it in my local browser.

**Is there a standard checklist of commands to run or things to check for before being able to run it locally?**

I assume I would have to look at the Gemfile and make sure everything is installed with the right versions. I already have npm installed. I installed rails, but it appears to be a different version than the Gemfile specified.

Other info: 
Operating system is Mac OS High Sierra; Browser: Chrome; Text Editor: Atom or VS Code are preferred.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Run `rails server` and catch any error, if any. Like dB setup, migrations etc...

Comment: When you go to project's directory, did you try `bundle install` command?  Make sure all dependencies in your Gemfile are available to your application

Comment: Thank you both! I get the same error for both: Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running the wrong version of ruby on your machine, check out [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to manage different versions.